# How does Eloquent's create()/fill work()?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I trying to set records in a row by doing this in my Model:

```
protected $fillable = ['completeness','task'];
    public  function add($records) {
        $this->create($records);
        $this->save();
    }
```

Though all values are there yet I am getting this:

> QLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column
>   "user_id" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains
>   (5, 120, null, very detailed, null, null, null, null, null, null,
>   2015-10-02 07:12:05, 2015-10-02 07:12:05).

How does `create()` or `fill()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fill()` method in eloquent is pretty straight forward. It takes an array of key value pairs (the `key` being the field name and the `value` being the...well value).

It:

1. Checks to see if the model is completely guarded i.e. `*` in the `$guarded` array or empty for the `$fillable` array. If so, it will eventually throw an Mass Assignment exception
2. Loops through the array (removes the table name from the key if it's present), checks to see if that field is mass assignable, mutates the value if a mutator is present for it, and then adds it to the `$attributes` array on the model.

`create()` creates a new instance of the model, then uses the `fill()` method and then saves and returns that new instance.

If you want to dig into it in more detail the file is located at:

`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for elaboration. But why am I getting NULL violation error? I am pretty sure I have all keys mentioned

Comment: Ok, guess calling `save()` explicitly doing this issue.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I apparently only read half of your post. You will be right regarding the `save()` method being the cause of the error.